# Increasing coverage with try-except-finally and a context-manager

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage

This is the flow that I have in my program

```
277: try:
278:    with open(r"c:\afile.txt", "w") as aFile:
...:        pass # write data, other exceptions/errors can occur here that have to be handled by the caller
329: except IOError as ex:
...:    print ex
332: finally:
333:    if os.path.exists(r"c:\afile.txt"):
334:        shutil.copy(r"c:\afile.txt", r"c:\dest.txt")
```

I've got all paths covered except for from line 278 to line 333

- I got a normal happy-flow.
- I stubbed `__builtin__.open` to raise IOError when the open is called with said file name

But how do I go from 278 to 333. Is this even possible?

---

Additional information:
- using [coverage.py 3.4](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) (we can't upgrade to 3.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One usually handles the flow in the following way

```
try:
    with open(r"C:\file.txt", "w") as aFile:
        a.File.write("!")
    if os.path.exists(r"C:\file.txt"):
        shutil.copy(r"C:\file.txt", r"C:\dest.txt")
except IOError as ex:
    print ex
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, however I still need the finally clause 'even' if anything goes wrong. (Including checking if the file exists. More is done in the finally than shown here so I can't get around that. There is stuff happening in the `# write data` part that can raise an error but needs to be excepted in the caller of this function and then the finally part still has to run.

Answer (score 2):

Daan, it may be that this represents a bug in coverage.py.  I assume from your description that you are using branch coverage, and that coverage.py is claiming 278-333 is missing.  If you could whittle this down to a reproducible test case, I'll create a ticket for it.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. I did find something else odd though. [If I run this script](http://codepad.org/0pURCZml) it does seem to work. line 13 is not reporting any missing branches. However lines 79, 85, 91 and 97 are reporting partial missing branches to two lines further (81, 87, 93, 99) Yet, the other problem still exists in our production code. (not a big deal for us though)